# Apply security header with proxy?

Tags: wcf, security, header

I have a custrom soapheader that looks like this :

```
[DataContract()]
    public class IntegrationHeader
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName;
        [DataMember]
        public string Password;
    }
```

Then I have the following code in a messageInspector :

```
if (request.Headers.Action == null || request.Headers.Action.ToString().Length < 1)
                return null;

            foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            {
                if (header.Namespace == "ns" && header.Name == "SecurityToken")
                {
                    loginHandler = new LoginHandler();

                    integrationHeader = request.Headers.GetHeader<IntegrationHeader>(header.Name, header.Namespace);
                    if ((userContext = loginHandler.LoginUser(integrationHeader.UserName, PassWordManager.DESEncrypt(integrationHeader.Password), Business.Entity.LoginType.Regular)) == null)
                        throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown username or invalid password");

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = userContext;

                    return null;
                }
            }

            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown username or invalid password");
```

When sending the following soap header with soapui it works fine :

```
   <soapenv:Header>
     <SecurityToken xmlns="ns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <Password xmlns="MyApp.ServiceImplementation">X</Password>
       <UserName xmlns="MyApp.ServiceImplementation">X</UserName>
     </SecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Then I try to do this from within a proxy generated WCF client :

using (client = new MyProxy())
                {

```
                IntegrationHeader ih = new IntegrationHeader { UserName = "X", Password = "X" };

                MessageHeader untyped = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SecurityToken", "ns", ih);
                using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
                {
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);
                }

                client.GetData(request);
            }
```

The problem is that there will be only 2 headers in the messageInspector when running this code and none of them will be the security header?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through the inspector code and verified that it's running as expected? As a side note: it's "SOAP", not "SOUP" ;-)

Comment: @Jeroen > Yes the request.Headers in After ReceiveRequest(service side) will have two headers. The first one have Namespace = http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none, header.Name = To and the second have the same Namespace but header.Name = Action. I do not get why the header is nog added?

Comment: Maby this is a namespace problem? The IntegrationHeader is placed in the namespace MyApp.DataContracts.OSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct solution :

```
            IntegrationHeader ih = new IntegrationHeader { UserName = "X", Password = "X" };

            MessageHeader untyped = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SecurityToken", "ns", ih);
            using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);
                client.GetData(request);
            }
```

The service call most be done within the using else the security header will be removed from the outgoing context.